# Android - Is it possible for a button to handle onClick events while a navigation drawer is open?

Tags: android

I have a DrawerLayout that is opened programatically by a button on the activity. When the navigation is open the button does not handle onClick events, is it possible to make just this button handle onClick events and keep the rest of the activity frozen? (as per standard DrawerLayout functionality)

Comment: Have you solved the problem ? I have a similar problem myself.

Comment: I have not solved it yet